# scrapy failed to fetch, but curl or browser can retrieve the page

Tags: scrapy

I have simple scrapy spider.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class ScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://api.ipify.org?format=json',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('================Request: %s, IP address: %s' % (response.request, response.text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(ScraperSpider)
    process.start()
```

However, it gives an error:

```
2023-12-18 23:56:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET https://api.ipify.org?format=json> (referer: None)
2023-12-18 23:56:34 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://api.ipify.org?format=json>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2023-12-18 23:56:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

But actually the url can be fetched with curl or browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `/` before `?` in the url:

```py
import scrapy


class ScraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('================Request: %s, IP address: %s' % (response.request, response.json().get('ip')))
```

Output:

```py
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api.ipify.org/?format=json> (referer: None)
[scraper] INFO: ================Request: <GET https://api.ipify.org/?format=json>, IP address: X.X.X.X
```